# tidyverse mutate with an external vector whose elements are column values in a data frame

Tags: r, quosure

Let's assume the following vector:

```
prices <- c(10, 15, 20, 30)
```

and the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(count = c(1, 3, 2, 4))
```

What I want to do is, depending on the `count` value in `df`, taking the `1:count` values from the prices vector and sum these up in my data frame.

So I thought I could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(sum = sum(!!prices[1:count]))
```

However, this gives an error:

```
Error in quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all") : 
  object 'count' not found
```

I guess it's because it looking into the external vector and then searching for `count` in the global environment, however, it only exists in df.

So question is how can I feed in this external vector into my data frame an reference its elements by the `count` values?

Expected output would be:

```
  count sum
1     1  10
2     3  45
3     2  25
4     4  75
```

Comment: Here, I believe you need `rowwise()`

Comment: why not using `cumsum(c(10, 15, 20, 30))`?

Comment: Let's assume the count var would be "1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2" or sth. like that. In real-life it won't be nicely sorted with ordered increments. Will update my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sapply`. And use `.GlobalEnv$` if necessary:

```r
df |>
  mutate(sum = sapply(count, \(x) sum(.GlobalEnv$prices[1:x])))

#   count sum
# 1     1  10
# 2     3  45
# 3     2  25
# 4     4  75
```

Comment: Nice solution. Which, as a nice side effect, would also work if count = 0 (need to change the prices subscript to [0:x] then, but then it works).

Answer (score 4):

You may subset `prices` with help of `count` and then use `cumsum`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(sum = cumsum(prices[count]))

#  count sum
#1     1  10
#2     2  25
#3     3  45
#4     4  75
```

Based on your comment on other answer if there is a possibility that the dataframe can have a column named `prices` then this will not work. In such case specify `.GlobalEnv` to explicitly use `prices` from global environment.

```
df <- data.frame(count = 1:4, prices = 4:1)

df %>% mutate(sum = cumsum(.GlobalEnv$prices[count]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Short and elegant.

Comment: fetching from the global environment like this makes me nervous, better use `.env` IMO

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `df` in `rowwise()`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(rowwise(df), total = sum(prices[1:count]))
```

Output:

```
  count total
  <int> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    25
3     3    45
4     4    75
```

Comment: Thanks, but this leaves the environment of the "prices" vector undeclared. Which works as long as it can be found in teh parent environment and as long as there is no column named "prices" in my df. But my gut feeling tells me that this could be dangerous, hence I'd like to explicitely specify the fact that I want to reference the external vector.

Comment: You can use `.env$prices` instead of `prices` for that effect